# How to group a calculated column by multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have this dataframe as listed underneath.

```
import pandas as pd

db_docks = pd.DataFrame(db_top_25, columns = ['from_station_id', 'to_station_id', 'hour', 'day','dpcapacity_start', 'dpcapacity_end'])
```

Image of sample data as I can't embed it directly
[image: Image of sample data as I can't embed it directly]

What I need to do is create a new dataframe that is grouped by 'hour', 'day' and 'from_station_id'.
Afterwards I need to count the amount of 'from_station_id' and subtract the amount of 'to_station_id' which is the main column that needs to be grouped by 'hour', 'day' and 'from_station_id'  .

I know that I need to use .groupby and most likely .transform but I have no idea how to even start coding this syntax so I really need help.

Thanks advance.

Edit:

I have tested

```
db_docks = pd.DataFrame(db_top_25.groupby(['from_station_id', 'day',
'hour'])['year'].count())
db_docks.reset_index()
```

Which returns this result, which is correct, I just need to add the column of counts of instances of 'from_station_id' minus count of instances of 'to_station_id':
[image: this result, which is correct, I just need to add the column of counts of instances of 'from_station_id' minus count of instances of 'to_station_id']

In response to @Kenan

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'from_station_id':  [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
        'day': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
        'hour': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
        }
```

The expected output is that I am able to know the count of how many instances of from_station_id occurs in each of 'from_station_id' in relation to the day and hour.

Comment: can you post a dataframe we can test with and the expected output

Comment: @Kenan hello, I edited the post with a dataframe, don't know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group your DataFrame by *hour*, *day* and *from_station_id*, then
each group will contain just **one** *from_station_id*, so there is no point
to count the amount of different values.

So maybe you want to group on *hour* and *day* **only**? (this makes more sense).

To have more than one group, I extended your data slightly, such that it
contains two groups (when grouping by *hour* and *day*):

```
   from_station_id  to_station_id  hour  day  dpcapacity_start  dpcapacity_end
0               56             78    22    4              20.0            30.0
1               66             77    22    4              23.0            11.0
2               66             77    23    4              23.0            11.0
3              110             77    23    4              23.0            31.0
4              110            289    23    4              15.0            19.0
5               81             41    23    4              39.0            19.0
6               56             77    23    4              27.0            31.0
```

Then, to compute your difference between the number of different *from_station_id*
and *from_station_id*, within each group, define the following function:

```
def dif(grp):
    n1 = grp.from_station_id.unique().size
    n2 = grp.from_station_id.unique().size
    return n1 - n2
```

Then apply it to each group:

```
db_docks.groupby(['hour', 'day']).apply(dif)
```

The result is a *Series*:

```
hour  day
22    4      0
23    4      1
```

where:

- *hour* and *day* are keys of each group,
- the value column (without name) contains your difference.

E.g. group for hour *23* and day *4* contains:

- 4 *from_station_id*s (66, 110, 81 and 56),
- 3 *to_station_id*s (77, 289 and 44),

so their difference is just *1*.

Maybe it is not just what you need, but anyway you have now some clue
as how to program grouppinig.

Comment: Hi @Valdi_Bo , this looks almost like what we need, however is it possible to also group by the from_station_id. What we are looking to see is which stations are the most active by what hour and day, so the count of how many 'from_station_id' (the amount of people who left from that station.

Comment: You can add *from_station_id* to the "groupby list", actually even with no change in other code. But in this case *n1* will be always *1*.